# Dynamic template "Includes" with django

Tags: python, django

I am building a Django website and my side bar can have different elements for different users. So my main sidebar template has a div for every plugin to be included and the specific HTML for every one of these plugins is included in their own template file.

example:

```
  <div id="plugins">
    <div id="plugin1">
      {% include 'plugin1.html' %}
    </div>
    <div id="plugin2">
      {% include 'plugin2.html' %}  
    </div>
  </div>
```

Now I want to build this list dynamically how could I do it? As the template is only parsed once so I could not send it a '{% include 'plugin1.html'}' string in the context

Any ideas?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use a variable inside the `include` tag:

```
{% include my_user_html %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a variable in the view as above containing your template or you can use a template tag to generate the template path for you based on another variable, i.e. a phase. Register the following tag, customize it to your needs:

```
@register.filter
def get_template_phase(template_string, phase):
    template_string = template_string.replace('<', '{').replace('>', '}')
    return template_string.format(phase=phase)
```

Place the above in your templatetags and register it.

Usage:

```
{% include 'includes/home__<phase>.html'|get_template_phase:'nomination' %}
```